# How to get inner html with enzyme? (html content)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, enzyme

in Enzyme, How we can get the content of the element, but as html?

(`.text()` returns text, `.html()` returns outerHTML)

```
const wrapper = shallow(<div><b>foo</b><span>cool</span></div>);
wrapper.text() // 'foocool' , like innerText in dom
wrapper.html() // '<div><b>foo</b><span>cool</span></div>' , like outerHTML in dom
wrapper.????() // '<b>foo</b><span>cool</span>' , <--------- like innerHTML in dom
```

Edit:

This works but isn't there a more convenient way to get it?

```
wrapper.children().map(el => el.html()).join('')
```

Comment: @ggorlen No problem, yeah tha's right. `html()` returns `<div><b>foo</b><b>bar</b></div>` and `.children(0).html()` returns error when there are multiple children.

Comment: @ggorlen i played with it and this works however it's so unconvanient to use: `wrapper.children().map(el => el.html()).join('')`

Comment: Yeah that works but you're right, it seems like a better way should be possible. I'm not familiar enough with Enzyme to know but watching the thread here.

Answer (score 5):

```
expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('<b>foo</b><span>cool</span>')
```

Comment: expect(wrapper.contains([
<b>foo</b>,
<span>cool</span>
])).to.equal(true);